# Can someone check my answers for this easy AP Calc related rates question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

**A pizza chef begins to spin a constant volume of dough to make a pie by spinning and tossing the dough into the air, such that the dough takes on a cylindrical shape. The dough’s radius increases while the height decreases, but the dough remains a cylinder.**

**At time $ = _1$, the height of the dough is $\frac{1}{2}$inch, the radius of the dough is 16 inches, and the radius of the dough is increasing at a rate of 2 inches per minute.**

**a. At time $_1$, at what rate is the area of the “top” of the pizza (the part with the toppings) increasing with respect to time? Show the computations that lead to your answer, and indicate units of measure.**

$A=\pi r^2$

$\frac{dA}{dt}=2r*\frac{dr}{dt}=2*16*2=64inch^2$ per minute

**b. At time $t_1$, at what rate is the height of the dough decreasing with respect to time?**

$V=\pi r^2 h$

$\frac{dV}{dt}=\pi r^2 *\frac{dh}{dt}+2\pi rh*\frac{dr}{dt}$

Since $V$ is a constant, $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is 0.

So $0=\pi(16^2)*\frac{dh}{dt}+2\pi*16*1/2*2$

$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{2\pi*16}{16^2\pi}=\frac{-1}{8}$ inches per minute

**c. Write an expression for the rate of change of the height of the dough with respect to the radius in terms of height $ℎ$ and radius $$. We are not looking for $\frac{dh}{dt}$, since that is the derivative with respect to time, not radius. But: $\frac{dh/dt}{dr/dt}=\frac{dh}{dr}$**

$0=\pi r^2*\frac{dh}{dt}+2\pi rh*\frac{dr}{dt}$

$-2\pi rh * \frac{dr}{dt}=\pi r^2*\frac{dh}{dt}$

$\frac{dh/dt}{dr/dt}=\frac{dh}{dr}=\frac{-2\pi rh}{\pi r^2}=\frac{-2h}{r}$

Comment: My only complaint is that if some doofus put toppings on the pizza *before* spinning it, surely by the time its radius reached 16 inches, they would all be gone, leaving the pizza with no "top" per the given definition! Other than a missing minus sign on $\frac {2\pi(16)}{16^2\pi}$ in the final equation of (b) (which reappears on the answer), your math is correct.